# Gather data from drupal and export to CSV on schedule

Tags: drupal, csv, export

We have a drupal site and we wish to export data from this site in the form of several CSV files. I'm aware of the Views module addins that make this a very simple process on demand, but what we're looking for is a way to automate this process through cron.

Most likely, we'll end up having to either write a standalone PHP file we can then access with cron to complete this action, or a custom module.

I first wanted to check to ensure that there isn't already a module or set of modules out there that will do what we're looking for. How would you accomplish this issue?

The end result is that these csv files will reside on the server for other services to pick up and import into their own systems or be distributed with rsync or something similar.

Best practices suggestions would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do with cron,

- Set up views with cvs data in them
- Then add `wget <path to your cvs view>` or the path of a script which does everything you need, in your crontab.